# Integration issue regarding the convolution of Weibull distribution

Tags: r, continuous-integration, convolution, weibull

Hi I was trying to compute the convolution of Weibull distribution as follows with parameter t, lambda(scale parameter) and k:

```
f.x <- function(x,lambda,k){
  dweibull(x,k,lambda)
}
cum <- function(T,lambda,k)
{ 
  return(1 - exp(-(T/lambda)^k))
}

F1_t = function(t,lambda,k){
  cum(t,lambda,k)
}
F2_t = function(t,lambda,k){
  integrate(function(x) F1_t(t-x,lambda,k)*f.x(x,lambda,k),0,t)$value

}
F3_t = function(t, lambda ,k){
  integrate(function(x) F2_t(t-x,lambda,k)*f.x(x,lambda,k),0,t)$value
}
```

Where F2_t and F3_t are the convolution definition of the second and third convolution，F2_t works fine but as I evaluated F3_t with

```
F3_t(1,1,2)
```

I got the following warning from R:

```
 Error in integrate(function(x) F1_t(t - x, lambda, k) * f.x(x, lambda,  : 
  length(upper) == 1 is not TRUE
```

I am wondering why this problem appears and how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, unlike `F1_t`, `F2`is not vectorized, meaning it does not return a vector of results for a vector of `t`.

Observe that

```
F1_t(c(1,2), 1, 1)
```

works fine, while

```
F2_t(c(1,2), 1, 1)
```

fails because you cannot provide a vector of upper integration limits to `integrate`.

So, the solution is to vectorize `F2_t`:

```
F2_t = function(t,lambda,k){
  sapply(t, function(y) integrate(function(x) F1_t(t-x,lambda,k)*f.x(x,lambda,k), lower = 0, upper = y)$value)
}
```

With the code above for `F2_t`, `F3_t(1,1,2)` runs fine.

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed explanation, so basically I have to vectorise the parameter t in this case so that it can provide an upper limit to the integration function F2_t? As I work for further convolution like F4_t, I got another warning that `Error in integrate(function(x) F2_t(t - x, lambda, k) * f.x(x, lambda,  : 
  maximum number of subdivisions reached ` even though I adjust the subdivision  of integration to  2000000000000.

Comment: It is a numerical integration issue. Play with tolerance and the number of subdivisions.

Comment: Hi I figured out where the problem is: the F2_t function should be:                           `F2_t = function(t,lambda,k){
  sapply(t, function(y) integrate(function(x) F1_t(y-x,lambda,k)*f.x(x,lambda,k), lower = 0, upper = y)$value)
}` instead of: `sapply(t, function(y) integrate(function(x) F1_t(t-x,lambda,k)*f.x(x,lambda,k), lower = 0, upper = y)$value)`, thanks again for the suggestion :D